# Google script write one cell to range i nanother Spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

pulling my hair a bit here.

I'm trying to build a "database-like" structure on Google Sheets (modify entry  in one document, it gets updated elsewhere).

- 2 spreadsheets, need to move data from one to another
- select SINGLE CELL on "Spreadsheet1", copy to a RANGE of cells on "Spreadsheet2"
- I got past many errors and fixed them but this one is invincible:

**Range not found (line 10, file "Code")**

What am I doing wrong?

```
function ImportDataRange() {

  var activeSs = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = activeSs.getSheetByName("PRODUCT dashboard");
  var ssOrigin = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1gF-IsnPdnjAaoUSwOOaBfWTmK1eVzxDG87XPzjjsWxA");
  var sheetOrigin = ssOrigin.getSheetByName("INITIAL_BUDGETS");

  for (var i = 7; i < 26; i++) {

    var rangeOrigin = sheetOrigin.getRange("i, 1");
    var dataOrigin = rangeOrigin.getValues();

    for (var i = 10; i < 275; i += 6) {
      sheet.getRange("i, 1").setValues(dataOrigin);
    }
  }

}
```

You probably got it but I need to: copy A7 from document1 into 15 cells of document2, than take cell A8 form document1 copy into next 15 cells of document2, then take A9.... You get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I would do it:

```
function ImportDataRange() {

  var activeSs = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(),
      sheet = activeSs.getSheetByName("PRODUCT dashboard"),
      rangeSheet = sheet.getRange(10, 1, 265), // 3rd number is the number of rows to get into the range, as described in documentation
      valsSheet = rangeSheet.getValues(); //Get all values in a double array, this is to keep any previous values in the sheet, also it already gets the array just as it is needed to use in setValues()
      ssOrigin = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1gF-IsnPdnjAaoUSwOOaBfWTmK1eVzxDG87XPzjjsWxA"),
      valsOrigin = ssOrigin.getRange(7, 1, 15).getValues(), // Same as the other getRange, gets 15 lines, starting in line 7
      sheetOrigin = ssOrigin.getSheetByName("INITIAL_BUDGETS");

  for ( origins in valsOrigin  ) { // For each value in the valsOrigin array, do something -> in each loop origins will be the next index, Eg. 0, then 1, then 2...
    for (var i = 10; i < 275; i += 6) {
      i = (+i) + (+origins); // Add the origins so it don't begin in the same line, altough it will start to overwrite after 6 loops, you should look into this logic - also, the '+' converts it to number, as they can be strings
      valsSheet[i][0] = valsOrigin[origins][0]; // Puts the current value of origins in the target array
    }
  }
  rangeSheet.setValues( valsSheet ); // Inserts all values at once in the range
}
```

Minimized SpreadsheetApp calls, those are the costly one in time, which is limited in GAS, also makes for a cleaner code.

Comment: Hmmm... seems I might have jumped the gun here. I'm getting a syntax error on line for ( origins in valsOrigin ) ... Any ideas? Also, could you please explain the loop a bit I'm doing my best to decipher it ... I see you are changing values in valsSheet from the first range you got by getRange and setting these new values in the second to last line of code. Thanks

Comment: There was a '.' after the `valsSheet` in line 14, it didn't belong there, forgot to delete, I'll leave some comments in the code for better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of your quotes in the getRange() parameters, you're not using a string.  Just need `.getRange(i, 0)`.

Also, if you're just getting one cell as your range and one setting value, you can use `.setValue()`.